# How can I make an app to load my website

Tags: android, iphone, mobile

Ive been asked to make a native iphone and android app for a client which will just load there mobile ready website (ecommerce site).

All that this app will need to do is act as a web browser for a single domain.

Anyone know a simple way to do this? I will have no access to the website files or database at all.

Comment: No one will be able to help you, unless you post the things you have tried and/or problem you have encountered.

Answer (score 1):

This question is too broad, but I'll try to answer. You can create an app that actually the only thing it does is opening a web.

In iOS, just create a Single View App and add a `UIWebView` to it, and load your webpage. There's a lot of documentation around on how to do this, from creating the project to load the web.

In Android would be something similar using a `WebView`. same as before, there's a lot of documentation, don't expect people to give it to you done here.

Answer (score -2):

I agree, this question is very broad, but I can try to help. The simplest way to create an app to link to your web site would be to use Adobe Flash ©. You could either Google how to make an app via Flash, or follow up on the program. What you are asking (using Flash) would be very simple. You can create an app for Android or IOS using Flash.